# What does putting an exclamation point (!) in front of an object reference variable do?

Tags: vb6

What does putting an exclamation point (`!`) in front of an object reference variable do in Visual Basic 6.0?

For example, I see the following in code:

```
    !RelativePath.Value = mstrRelativePath
```

What does the `!` mean?

Comment: Sure that's not `rs!RelativePath.Value`?

Comment: yep, I'm sure.  I copied it straight out of the block of code.

Comment: ahhh...I see...It's within a `With` block.  Specifically, `adoRS`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is almost certainly a statement inside a With block:

```
  With blah
    !RelativePath.Value = mstrRelativePath
  End With
```

which is syntax sugar for

```
  blah("RelativePath").Value = mstrRelativePath
```

which is syntax sugar for

```
  blah.DefaultProperty("RelativePath").Value = mstrRelativePath
```

where "DefaultProperty" is a property with dispid zero that's indexed by a string.  Like the Fields property of an ADO Recordset object.

Somewhat inevitable with sugar is that it produces tooth decay.  This is the reason you have to use the **Set** keyword in VB6 and VBA.  Because without it the compiler doesn't know whether you meant to copy the object reference or the object's default property value.  Eliminated in vb.net.

Comment: In your answer you said, "which is syntax sugar for". Is it *only* syntax sugar? I'm wondering if perhaps it might help speed up runtime of the application as well or are there other side effects with using a `!` instead of writing out all of the code.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>The exclamation point is acting as a member access operator it seems...</strike>

> Member Access Operators
>
> To access a member of a type, you use
>   the dot (.) or exclamation point (!)
>   operator

---

I take that back. It is this:

> Exclamation Point (!) Operator Use the
>   ! operator only on a class or
>   interface as a dictionary access
>   operator. The class or interface must
>   have a default property that accepts a
>   single String argument. The identifier
>   immediately following the ! operator
>   becomes the string argument to the
>   default property.