# What is the difference between Form5!ProgressBar.Max and Form5.ProgressBar.Max?

Tags: vb6

I'm looking at a piece of very old VB6, and have come across usages such as

```
Form5!ProgressBar.Max = time_max
```

and

```
Form5!ProgressBar.Value = current_time
```

Perusing the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366097/what-does-putting-an-exclamation-point-in-front-of-an-object-reference-varia) and reading this page [here](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2003/12/say_no_to_the_v.html), I deduce that these things mean the same as

```
Form5.ProgressBar.Max = time_max
Form5.ProgressBar.Value = current_time
```

but it isn't at all clear that this is the case. Can anyone confirm or deny this, and/or point me at an explanation in words of one syllable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Form5!ProgressBar` is almost exactly equivalent to `Form5.ProgressBar`

As far as I can remember there is one difference: the behaviour if the `Form5` object does not have a `ProgressBar` member (i.e. the form does not have a control called ProgressBar). The dot-notation is checked at compile time but the exclamation-mark notation is checked at run time.

- `Form5.ProgressBar` will not compile.
- `Form5!ProgressBar` will compile but will give an error at runtime.

IMHO the dot notation is preferred in VB6, especially when accessing controls. The exclamation mark is only supported for backward-compatibility with very old versions of VB.

Comment: The ! notation is also used for the default accessor function/property, e.g. `RecordSet!Blah` is the same as `RecordSet.Fields("Blah")`.

Comment: @Deanna Yes, as explained in the [link given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366097/what-does-putting-an-exclamation-point-in-front-of-an-object-reference-varia) in Brian's question, which he says he has read.

Answer (score 1):

The default member of a Form is (indirectly) the Controls collection.

The bang (!) syntax is used for collection access in VB, and in many cases the compiler makes use of it to early bind things that otherwise would be accessed more slowly through late binding.

Far from deprecated, it is often preferable.

However in this case since the default member of Form objects is `[_Default] As Object` containing a reference to a `Controls As Object` instance, there is no particular advantage or disadvantage to this syntax over:

```
Form5("ProgressBar").Value
```

I agree that in this case however it is better to more directly access the control as a member of the Form as in:

```
Form5.ProgressBar.Value
```

Knowing the difference between these is a matter of *actually knowing* VB.  It isn't simply syntactic though, the two "paths" do different things that get to the same result.

Hopefully this answer offers an explanation rather merely invoking voodoo.